# Loading the content of a JSON file with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, json, requirejs

I am trying to load a simple JSON file into a variable and I am running into walls.

Here is the code I use :

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"> 
    <title>Require test</title> 
    <script charset="utf-8" src="require.js"></script>
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      root = require('./data_test_v2.json');
      console.log(root);
    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

And this is the error I get :

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "data_test_v2.json" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
```

The require.js file is the latest version of RequireJS (from `https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/comments/require.js`).

Seems like a very basic problem.. any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can use RequireJS to load JSON files, but you will need a [JSON plugin](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins) for that.

Also, you have to slightly amend your code, as RequireJS is async. It requires you to provide an array of required dependencies to load as the first argument and a callback as a second one. The callback will be executed and the loaded dependencies will be injected as parameters.

```html
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"> 
    <title>Require test</title> 
    <script charset="utf-8" src="require.js"></script>
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      root = require(['./data_test_v2.json'], (json) => { console.log(json); });
      console.log(root);
    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. What I don't understand, it's how I can access the content in json after the call. As can be seen in the console, in `root`, there is not the content of the file but rather a "require object" I don't really understand.

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake in my code. Edited it already

Comment: @EdouardBatot tried to edit but somehow I am unable to do this. You should remove  `console.log(root);` and and check what is logging the `console.log(json);`

Answer (score -1):

The `require` function provided by **Node.js** will load **CommonJS** modules and **JSON**.

The `require` function provided by **Require.js** will load **AMD** modules.

They are not designed to be compatible. They have completely different APIs. Require.js **does not** support loading JSON.

---

If you want to load data from JSON with client-side code in the browser then use `fetch`, `XHTMLHttpRequest` or a library wrapped around one of them (such as `axios`).

Comment: I am not loading a JSon, I am reading a file (and its extension is JSon).

Comment: @EdouardBatot — Same thing.

Comment: RequireJS has had loader plugins for like a decade at. It's absolutely supported.